# Favicon and pictures not getting served by Flask to a React app

Tags: javascript, python, html, reactjs, flask

I have a Flask server that is set up like this

```
app = Flask(__name__,
            static_folder="dist/assets",
            static_url_path='/assets',
            template_folder="dist")


CORS(app)
socketio = SocketIO(app, cors_allowed_origins='*')
```

My Flask directory looks like this

```
Flask
|- Classes
|- dist
|- log
|- main.py
|- Settings
```

And the dist looks like this

```
dist
|- assets
|- index.html
|- MyFavicon.png
|- vite.svg
```

In flask I have a basic index route

```
@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template("index.html")
```

The index route loads, the problem is the assets and the favicon do not load

From the browser I get errors like this

```
GET
http://localhost:5000/MyFavicon.png
[HTTP/1.1 404 NOT FOUND 0ms]
```

And this is what the index.html looks like

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="icon" href="/MyFavicon.png" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <title>Monitor</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="root"></div>
<script type="module" src="/src/main.jsx"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone know if the problem is the way Flask is trying to serve the static files or is it the way I am referencing things on React side of things?

EDIT:

Also this is the directory in React

```
React
| - public
| - src
    | - assets
```

Where the favicon is in public, and the rest of my pictures are in assets

EDIT2:

Per @furas suggestion I tried moving all pictures into `/dist/assets/` and updating `index.html` to this

```
<link rel="icon" href="/assets/MyFavicon.png" />
```

But I got the same errors, I also tried adding in a route like this

```
@app.route('/assets/MyFavicon.png')
def favicon():
    print('serving favicon route')
    return send_file("dist/assets/YFavicon.png")
```

But I was never able to observe the print statement, I played around with the route and the `href` I am using, but I keep on getting the same errors

Comment: your Flask can server static files like `favicon` only from folder `dist/assets/MyFavicon.png ` (see your `static_folder=...`) and it can be server only as `https://.../assets/MyFavicon.png` (see your `static_url_path=...`). If you want to server it as `https://.../MyFavicon.png` then you may have to create `@app.route('/MyFavicon.png')` with `return send_file("MyFavicon.png")`. OR you may have to use `static_url_path='/'` but this can make problem with other `@app.route(...)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have `static_folder="dist/assets"` so you should keep files in `dist/assets`

```
dist
|- assets
|  |- MyFavicon.png
|  |- vite.svg
|
|- index.html
```

You have `static_url_path='/assets'` so you should use `/assets` for static files

```
href="/assets/MyFavicon.png"
```

---

To use `href="/MyFavicon.png"` you would need `static_url_path='/'`
but I don't know if this can make conflict with all `@app.route(...)`

Or you can create function only for this file

```py
@app.route('/MyFavicon.png')`
def favicon():
    #return send_file("dist/assets/MyFavicon.png")
    return send_file("dist/MyFavicon.png")
```

---

OR you should run it with `Apache`/`nginx` which will serve static files from `dist`

Comment: Hey thanks for the help, I tried moving the favicon into /assets , but it did not help :(

I also tried adding in the route but the front end never calls for it. Also worth mentioning that I have lot's of other pictures in /assets but none of them are found

Comment: you have to also use `/assets` in urls. `href="/assets/MyFavicon.png"` - both elements are important - `folder` and `url`.

Comment: To clarify I did try playing around with different href routes, but I wasn't able to get it to work. When I tried adding a route to explicitly serve the favicon, nothing ever reached it :( I updated the OP to provide a little more clarity, thanks!

Comment: maybe you runs other web server and it serves pages instead of `flask`.